# Using project hierarchy to aid in nuget package creation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I've got the following project hierarchy:

[image]

The projects on the left have dependencies on the projects that are on the right.

If I have multiple solutions that use a subset of these projects as references (references DO NOT EDIT below), **how can I create a nuget repository strategy to support this complex structure?**

[image]

Comment: Did you want to create a nuget package feed to support that complex structure? The complex structure should be reflected by the nuget package rather than nuget package feed. If you want create a nuget feed, this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview will help you.

Comment: what about this issue? Does my comment have any help to you? Would you please share more information about this issue?